# $\cos(\cos(\cdots(\cos(x))\cdots))$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, uniform-convergence, fixed-point-theorems

$\forall n\in \mathbb N$, Let $$f_n (x)=\underbrace{\cos(\cos(\cos(\cdots (\cos}_n(x\underbrace{))\cdots)}_n$$
It is known that $$\forall x\in\mathbb R,\space \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=0.7390851332\dots$$**Does the convergence uniform?**

Comment: This question has been asked and answered several times in the past.  See [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621993), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951133), and [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482075) for examples.  I'm personally rather fond of the version of the question to which I linked above, though I am biased in that regard.